# How to upload video file using AJAX JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying a lot to upload a video file but I am unable to do that. Please help me out with this. Thanks for helping in advance.

Here I am sharing a piece of code. This is my View Page.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="VideoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Video</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group no-margin-hr">
                        <label class="control-label" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0px;">Video Upload</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="ComplaintID2" value="0" />
                        <input id="VideoName" class="imgpreview" type="hidden" value="0" />
                        <input name="FileUpload1" id="FileUpload1" type="file" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="margin-top:23px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UploadVideos();" style="margin-top:23px;">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me share you my Javascript File.

```js
function UploadVideos() {
    try {
        var ID = $("#ComplaintID2").val();
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var fileUpload = $("#FileUpload1").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
            var fileData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }
            fileData.append("ID", ID);
            console.log(fileData);
        }
        else {
            alert("FormData is not supported.");
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}
```

And Last my Controller

```
public ActionResult UploadVideos() {
    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any()) {
        var image = CreateRandomKey();
        var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["ID"]);
        HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(pic);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filebase.FileName);
        string[] k = fileName.Split('.');
        string imgname = id + "_" + image + "." + k[1].ToString();
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/ComplaintVideo"), imgname);
        filebase.SaveAs(path);
        var result = new { status = imgname };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    var result1 = new { status = "101" };
    return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public static string CreateRandomKey() {
    string _allowedChars = "09876543212345678901234567890";
    Random randNum = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    char[] chars = new char[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = _allowedChars[randNum.Next(_allowedChars.Length)];
    }
    return new string(chars);
}
```

Please help me out with this problem. I am facing a lot of issues with this.

Comment: Where is your code to submit the file? Your JS creates the FormData object, but never does anything with it...?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have got my answer. Actually i am using same ID in two input box that's why it is not uploading. But now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much.